# What type of authentication is using here?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ado.net, windows-authentication

I got a hr based windows  application with sql server at bavk end  where a user will login using his username/password . This username and password were stored in a table in sql and they are authenticated based on the login details provided.

I got a few  question .

1) what type of authentication is using here, is there any generic term like , example :windows based or form based authentication ( not the case here)?

2) our  Client application   accessing server using  odbc data source and a  connection string Is  stored in installation folder pointing to odbc. How do server authenticate client request in this case?

Regards

Comment: if the connection string contains a userid and password, then you are using SQL authentication to authenticate to the database. If it has `Trusted_Connection=Yes` (or a DSN that specifies Windows auth), then it's using Windows authentication with the Windows credentials of the process. It is likely the application is separately using forms authentication at the app layer to authenticate and authorize the user from with the app, using the table you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

1) Database authentication?
2) Depends on database/connectionstring: Integrated Windows authentication (domain) or SQL Server authentication

Comment: can u show any links or details on how Database authentication works?